# Logstash: Send formatted metric events to Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, metrics

I am able to capture some metrics in `stdout` from events in `logstash` using the relevant plugin as follows:

in my `filter` file:

```
  if "somekeyword" in [tags] {
    metrics {
      meter => "events_somekeyword"
      flush_interval => 60
      add_tag => "metric_somekeyword"
    }
  }
```

in my`outputs` file

```
if "metric_somekeyword" in [tags] {
        stdout {
          codec => line {
            format => "Time: %{+YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z} | Metric: rate 1m | Client: SomeJeyword | Rate: %{[events_somekeyword][rate_1m]}"
          }
        }
```

My question is how to translate the **exact** same operation / formatting in terms of `elasticsearch` output.

e.g.

```
{
    "Metric Rate": "1m",
    "Client": "SomeKeyword",
    "Rate": "THE_ACTUAL_RATE_VALUE_HERE",
    "@timestamp": "2018-11-02T11:34:34.000Z",
}
```

I would also like (if possible) the `Rate` to be rounded to its nearest integer value;

The above should be grouped to per-day index

Comment: Can you show a sample document of how you'd like to store that information in ES?

Comment: @Val pls have a look in my question which has been edited;

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to parse your key value message like this

```
filter {
  kv { 
      source => "field_containing_the_message_to_parse"
      field_split => "|"
      value_split => ":"
  }
}
```

If that's what you want, there are more options available to customize your parsing https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-kv.html